# counting a string in pdf file using QTP

Tags: pdf, qtp, acrobat

I am trying to count the number of times a string exists in a pdf file. I used the below code, but it is going in infinite loop. The problem is after finding the string after the last page,it comes back to 1st page and repeats all the steps again. Does anyone have a solution for this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
siva

```
Dim AcroApp, AcroAVDoc  
Dim gPDFPath, bReset, nCount  
gPDFPath = "xyz.pdf"  

Set AcroApp = CreateObject( "AcroExch.App" )  
AcroApp.Show()  
Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject( "AcroExch.AVDoc" )   
If AcroAVDoc.Open( gPDFPath, "" ) Then  
    AcroAVDoc.BringToFront()  
    bReset = True : nCount = 0  
    Do While AcroAVDoc.FindText( "let", True, True, bReset )   
        bReset = False : nCount = nCount + 1   
        Wait 0, 200  
    Loop   
End If  
AcroApp.CloseAllDocs()  
AcroApp.Exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to QTP it has to do with Acrobat's API, a quick search returned [this link to the API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm).

It looks like the problem is that you're using a boolean for `bReset`, the documentation says:

```
VARIANT_BOOL FindText(BSTR szText, 
                      long bCaseSensitive, 
                      long bWholeWordsOnly, 
                      long bReset);
```

So `bReset` should be a long not a boolean.

> **`bReset`**: If a positive number, the search begins on the first page of the document. If 0, it begins on the current page.

In VBScript `False` is 0 and `True` is -1, so when you're sending `True` it could be that it's not considered a positive number, try using 1 instead.